# Interview Q: Detecting a fighting game moveset

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, state

I got this as an interview question and I'm wondering what the optimal way of designing this system would be. The problem:

Say you have a fighting game where certain button combinations represent a special move. Implement 2 functions **register_move([button combo],movename)** which takes in a list of button inputs and a movename string and **on_keypress(button)** which registers the current keypress and prints a movename if a button combo has been activated. The buttons are represented as characters: 'U','D','L','R','A','B'

Example:

```
register_move(['A','B','U'],"Uppercut")
on_keypress('A')
on_keypress('B')
on_keypress('U') -> print "Uppercut"
```

you can assume moves are registered before on_keypress so you don't have to retroactively look back at the previous keypresses. You can use any language you like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a [Deterministic Finite State Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton). The initial state is "no keys recognised". On each keypress, transition into a new state; if it is a final state you have a move. All undefined transitions transition into the starting state. For your example,

```
S --(a)--> A
A --(b)--> AB
AB --(u) --> ABU: process "Uppercut", move to S
X --(x)--> S
```

where `X` is any state, `x` is any input not otherwise covered by the rules.

More practically and less theoretically, you will end up with a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), so using a trie library should be sufficient. Root is "no input", walk it until a leaf, or restart on a mispress.

Comment: Sorry to revive this after so much time, but isn't more complicated string search required? e.g. (making up some syntax):

`register_move("ABABAC", "Uppercut");
"ABABABAC".for_each(on_keypress);`
You'd expect the very last character to trigger `Uppercut`, but using a trie or state machine it doesn't -- please let me know if I'm misunderstanding. I think you could combine a trie with a KMP failure function or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the limited number of moves, you don't need a super efficient finite state machine to handle this.

You could simply store the strings in `register_move`, and have `on_keypress` memorize the last potentially valid sequence.

- If the current key sequence is the prefix of at least one move (for instance "AB" being a prefix of "ABU"), you're done (just wait for the next keypress to see if a combo is reached).
- If the sequence is no prefix, reset the sequence to the last keypress (for instance "ABD" -> "D"). This clears previous keypresses that correspond to no moves.
- If the sequence corresponds to a move, perform the move (well, print it at least) and reset the sequence.

This would require to do a prefix search on every possible move combo, which is very quick if you have only a dozen or so. If for some reason you want to be quicker, you can indeed turn your list of combos into a prefix tree, but it would require a lot more code for little gain.